# How to store items safely?

Tags: fallout-4

In Skyrim and previous Fallout games, you needed a home to store your findings permanently.

Is this still the same in Fallout 4? And when will the first spot come in the main story line?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Workshop is a secure location to store items (the workshop in Sanctuary is available immediately upon exiting the vault). Actual items (ie: not junk) stored in your workshop store will not be broken down automatically during construction of other structures.

Generic containers can also be used for storage as they do not appear to be reset after a period of time (like previous Fallout games and other games using Fallout 4's game engine like Skyrim) - I've had a set of containers (filing cabinets) that I placed next to my Workshop in Sanctuary and I've been storing Power Armor components in one and holodiscs in the other - so far these have not reset (over a period of three weeks of game world time).

Comment: I too have gone a similar route, with containers in my settlement, although I store my power armour parts in the power armour crafting station.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd called the Workshop a secure location to store them, they might end up getting scrapped when building/modding...

Comment: Doesn't it only automatically scrap the items classified as "junk"?

Comment: @Dangerzone is correct.  i use my workshop to store everything since setting up supply lines means I can access my stash from almost every settlement.  Its super handy that way.

Comment: Worth noting that storage appears to be stored between any workbench-type structure in any given settlement - and not just Sanctuary (Red Rocket station is also very close to the start).

Comment: @Taegost Only Junk items are at risk of being automatically scrapped--and junk items are mainly (only?) for crafting anyway. Other item types are safe.

Comment: @FeralChimp - That's good to know, thank you, I wasn't willing to take that chance :)  I didn't know you could have direct access to the entire inventory with the supply lines, I thought it only pulled crafting mats from the other settlements...  I may never have to go back to Sanctuary again after reading this!

Comment: Well I can confirm that I've been using containers for my items for a while now and nothing has gone missing.

Comment: Be sure to store your mods in the Workshop so they are available when crafting armour and weapons.

Comment: You don't need to go to Concord to access the workshop in Sanctuary. Also, in previous Bethesda games, other containers wouldn't reset unless you didn't visit (load the cell, technically) for a long time (10-30 days in Skyrim, I believe).

Answer (score 5):

MOST containers are perfectly safe.  All containers you make with the workshop ARE safe.

However, I wouldn't store items for long in instanced areas just in case.
The Quarry area in particular, I lost all the items I stored there during my siege upon the place after the water drains out. Something about that place resets, so beware and don't store stuff there. So, if an instance has different quest tiers especially, watch out.

I have noticed that container items respawn with a high frequency in places I've already raided. Not sure why this is. Something to do with either continuing after a death instead of loading up a save.

Answer (score 0):

Early Game. It looks like the workbench etc, share storage in one area and link between settlements later. However, I have had some pre-built containers reset with new items. I didn't save anything that way so nothing was lost thankfully. However, if you build your own containers, of any type, in a settlement area where you could expand, those containers are safe.
For instance, at Red Rocket Truck Stop you have everything except the Chem Lab and the one at Sanctuary is just up the road. I cleared out some space left side of the Power Armor Station (by recycling what was there) and made a bunch of storage units for weapons and outside next to the Armor station I made a bunch more. Those have been fine as far as I can tell. 
Careful though, some don't allow you to stack another of its type very well. Play with it a bit. You can always recycle if you screw up (just make sure what you recycle is empty). I threw in a bed later because the Sanctuary settlers were always grabbing all the beds when I wanted a quick heal.

Comment: How is this different than the existing answer?